# complexity algorithm recurrence relation

Tags: algorithm, math, complexity-theory, recurrence, master-theorem

```
int function(int n){
if (n<=1)
 return 1;
else 
 return (2*function(n/2));
}
```

What is the recurrence relation T(n) for running time , and why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The complexity-function of this algorithm would be

```
T(n) = T(n / 2) + 1
T(1) = 1
```

Applying the [master-theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem), we would get

```
a = 1
b = 2
c = 0 (1 = n^0)

log b(A) = log2(1) = 0 = 0 c, thus case 2
apply values and the result is O(log n).
```

As @guillaume already correctly stated, this can be solved a lot easier by using a linear function though.

Comment: @cstac that's the solution that comes up when using the master-theorem (unless I made any mistake with the calculation - I'll doublecheck that). Probably he expected the exact solution? There should be some note about whats wrong. Or simply ask him

Comment: @cstac the exact solution by precisely solving the recurrence-relation. The master-theorem is only applicable if you want to find the complexity-order of the recurrence.

Comment: @cstac I'd simply ask the teacher though. I haven't used the master-theorem for 2 years. There's a good chance I made a mistake. I'm just searching for it.

Comment: I solved that relation and is correct, the problem is , if I must have th number 2 at the begin..

Comment: @cstac sry, I didn't copy that 2 at the beginning. That's where the mistake was. My solution isn't correct, since `a` should be 2, not 1. I've corrected that. Result is linear now though, not logarithmic. And I don't exactly understand your question

Comment: @cstac sry, I'm completely tired, actually I intended to go to sleep an hour ago... . I'll have a look tomorrow. I just noticed the code above isn't `T`, but we need to calculate `T` for the code.

Comment: @cstac I've double-checked everything. Unless I've missed something `O(log n)` is correct.

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate directly: it is the nearest 2^n, largest or equal.

You calculate L=log2(n), and you take 2^L, or 2^(L+1)

Complexity is O(log2 N) : log2 N operations.